# Batch delete all JPG images that start with letter A and a digit

Tags: batch-file

I am writing a batch file that deletes all JPG images starting with "A" and having the second character numeric, example: A23.jpg, A2334.jpg, etc.

As I am new to batch programming, I managed just to glue several code lines as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%a in (A*.JPG) do (
    set secondChar=%%a:~1,2%
    for /f "delims=0123456789" %%i in ("%secondChar") do set var=%%i
    if defined var (del %%a) else ()
)
```

Comment: `%%~a:~1,2%` cannot work, you must assign `%%~a` to an interim variable, then you can so sub-string expansion on that. Ensure to properly use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be done with a single command line:

```
for %%I in (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9) do del /F /Q A%%I*.jpg 2>nul
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `del /?`
- `for /?`

Read also the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)).

Answer (score 1):

Mofi`s way with a counting loop:

```
for /l %%I in (0,1,9) do del /F /Q "A%%I*.jpg" 2>nul
```

Using for /f with dir and filtering with findstr

```
for /f "delims=" %%I in (
  'dir /b "A*.jpg"^|findstr /I "^A[0-9].*\.jpg"'
) Do del /F /Q "%%I" 2>nul
```

Comment: Thanks LotPings. Your input is appreciated (althout I need some time to digest everything)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on your attempt:

```cmd
for %%F in ("A*.jpg") do (
    for /F "tokens=1* delims=0123456789" %%K in ("%%~F") do (
        if /I "%%K"=="A" if not "%%L"=="" (
            del /F "%%~F"
        )
    )
)
```